# Usar mas de un delimitador con StringTokenizer

Tags: java, eclipse

quisiera saber como podria en java eclipse usando la clase StringTokenizer para declarar mas de 1 delimitador para que me separe el String en tokes.
Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Podes dar un ejemplo de como sería lo que tiene que separar? Por otro lado, en lugar de StringTokenizer la recomendación actual es usar split() de la clase String.

Comment: Lo que tendria que separar puede ser cualquier texto que me pasan como parametro en un archivo "File" podria ser: hola, esto es una prueba.Chau" y tendria que separarlo en palabras, por eso queria saber como usar mas de 1 delimitador para excluir las comas puntos y demas

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenta @Juan, para eso necesitas emplear split e incluir expresiones regulares(Regex). Un ejemplo sería:

```
String [] tokens = stringCualquiera.split("-|\\.");
```

Te dejo un enlace a la documentación oficial sobre [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

---

Te dejo un ejemplo más claro, pero una vez que se tiene el fundamento, probar es muy sencillo y la mejor manera para aprender (leyendo y probando). Te dejo un par de ejemplos, si miras expresiones regulares podrás hacer las combinaciones que desees.Si quieres separar con '.' y ',':

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String stringCualquiera = "Pues es como decir, por poner un ejemplo, que se delimitan con puntos. Y tambien valen las comas y los letras a y b";
        String [] tokens = stringCualquiera.split("[,.]");


        for (int i = 0; i <= tokens.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Imprimiría:

```
Pues es como decir
 por poner un ejemplo
 que se delimitan con puntos
 Y tambien valen las comas y los letras a y b
```

Y si quieres que el delimitador sea tanto una ',' como una 'a' o una 'e'.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String stringCualquiera = "Pues es como decir, por poner un ejemplo, que se delimitan con puntos. Y tambien valen las comas y los letras a y b";
        String [] tokens = stringCualquiera.split("[,ae]");


        for (int i = 0; i <= tokens.length-1; i++) {
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que imprimiría:

```
Pu
s 
s como d
cir
 por pon
r un 
j
mplo
 qu
 s
 d
limit
n con puntos. Y t
mbi
n v
l
n l
s com
s y los l
tr
s 
 y b
```

Si quieres mirar las expresiones regulares en Java, puedes hacerlo [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, me explicas porque van las dos "\\" antes del punto?

Comment: Un punto en una expresión regular significa cualquier carácter. En el ejemplo queremos que sea un punto como tal y no cualquier carácter. También si te ha valido la respuesta del compañero Hugo, pues la valores como válida.

Comment: Hola @ivaan, se trata de expresiones regulares. Te deje un enlace en mi respuesta donde puedes verlas y aprender sobre ellas ya que son muy útiles en muchos campos. Puedes probar a hacer distintas combinaciones que se ajusten a tus necesidades. Respecto a tu pregunta, es lo que comenta Diego.

Comment: muchas gracias a los 2